# React concat current state(array) with another array using useState

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, use-state

The initial state in my component is an array of objects. I am using Redux to fetch another array of objects, as you can see in my below code. I am checking that `outCalls` is true, if it is I am creating a new array of objects that can be joined with the state.

However in my dependencies array it says I am missing `data`. If I add it, it creates a mad loop and I get errors. As it currently is, the array of objects doesn't get joined to the state.

```
useEffect(() => {
        if(outCalls) {
            const transformedOutgoingCalls = outCalls.filter(call => call.contractor._id === props.contractor._id).map(c => ({
                type: 'Outgoing Call',
                contact_person: c.contact_person,
                logged_by: c.created_by.name,
                date: c.time_created,
                link: <> <LinkContainer to={`/outgoing-calls/${c._id}`} className='text-success' style={{ cursor: 'pointer'}}><Eye /></LinkContainer> </>
            }))
            const newData = [...data, transformedOutgoingCalls]
            setData(newData)
        }
    }, [outCalls, props.contractor._id])
```

Comment: Where do you declare the variable `data`?

Comment: Try to change setData to its callback version, in which you have access to the previous state, and useEffect will no longer complain `setData(prevData => [...prevData, tranformedOutgoingCalls])`

Comment: when the `contractor._id` is 1 your state will have a list only with `contractor._id` 1 info . Now if the `contractor._id` is 2 does your state have a list with both the contractors info or just contractor 2 info ?

Comment: @Shyam Just contractor 2, so it is getting the right data in terms of the contractor id, just duplicating it when i return to the page

Answer (score 1):

You can set state in useEffect without declaring `data` as dependency like below:-

```
useEffect(() => {
        if(outCalls) {
            const transformedOutgoingCalls = outCalls.filter(call => call.contractor._id === props.contractor._id).map(c => ({
                type: 'Outgoing Call',
                contact_person: c.contact_person,
                logged_by: c.created_by.name,
                date: c.time_created,
                link: <> <LinkContainer to={`/outgoing-calls/${c._id}`} className='text-success' style={{ cursor: 'pointer'}}><Eye /></LinkContainer> </>
            }))
            setData(prevData => [...prevData, ...transformedOutgoingCalls]);
        }
    }, [outCalls, props.contractor._id])
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! Will accept when it lets me

Comment: There is actually a problem happening, if I navigate to a page and go back, it does it again and adds it on top of what was already there. So everything is now there twice. I tried adding another `useEffect` at the top and put `setData([])` but nothing changes

Comment: The only thing i see here is having the outCalls as a dependency . since outCalls is an array its reference should not be changing between the re-renders else it will lead to infinite re-render causing maximum depth exceeded error .

Comment: where you are getting the outCalls from ? . Is it from redux ?

Comment: @Shyam Yes. It says outCalls needs to be a dependency

Comment: @BranOIE when you go back and change page at that time does your component unmounts?

Comment: @PriyankKachhela Yes

Comment: Then it should not be any problem because after unmount, component does not have any way to hold states so on new mount it will always have data as blank array.

Comment: @PriyankKachhela Maybe it doesn't unmount then haha

Answer (score 0):

Since your state is dependent on outCalls and props.contractor._id . Instead of having a state exclusively you can just have a variable.

```
// read the data from the store
const outCalls = useSelector(....); 


// since the component re-render when ever there is change in props. Whenever your
// props.contractor._id changes we run this function and get the updated data.

const data = useMemo(() => {
   const transformedOutgoingCalls = outCalls.filter(call => call.contractor._id === props.contractor._id).map(c => ({
        type: 'Outgoing Call',
        contact_person: c.contact_person,
        logged_by: c.created_by.name,
        date: c.time_created,
        link: <> <LinkContainer to={`/outgoing-calls/${c._id}`} className='text-success' style={{ cursor: 'pointer'}}><Eye /></LinkContainer> </>
    }));

    return transformedOutgoingCalls
}, [outCalls, props.contractor._id])
```

Comment: It needs to be in state because there is multiple instances where I have to append to data. So like outcalls, there is more things in the store i need to fetch also and do the same with